# Different result from zlib deflation on iOS and Android. How to obtain same result?

Tags: java, android, ios, zlib, deflate

Currently in my iOS app I am using `zlib` to deflate data and I would like to implement the same logic in Android, so that the deflated data processed in these two platforms are compatible and can be transferred.

In the code below, both `inputString` are any random string like:

> Developers trust Stack Overflow to help solve coding problems and use Stack Overflow Careers to find job opportunities. We’re committed to making the internet a better place, and our products aim to enrich the lives of developers as they grow and mature in their careers.

In iOS, the following code segment is used:

```
NSData *rawData = [inputString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSInputStream * src = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:rawData];
[src open];
NSOutputStream * dest = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToMemory];
[dest open];
int res = [self deflateDataStream:src toOutputStream:dest level:Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION];
[dest close];
[src close];

if (res != Z_OK) return nil;

NSData *ret = [dest propertyForKey:NSStreamDataWrittenToMemoryStreamKey];

+ (int) deflateDataStream:(NSInputStream *)source toOutputStream:(NSOutputStream *)dest level:(int)level {
    int ret, flush;
    unsigned have;
    z_stream strm;
    unsigned char inBuf[CHUNK];
    unsigned char outBuf[CHUNK];

    strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
    strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
    ret = deflateInit2(&strm, level, Z_DEFLATED, (16+MAX_WBITS), MAX_MEM_LEVEL, Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY);
    if (ret != Z_OK) return ret;

    do {
        NSInteger res = [source read:inBuf maxLength:CHUNK];
        if (res < 0)  {
            NSLog(@"!!! Error reading stream: %ld %@", (long)source.streamStatus, source.streamError);
            (void)deflateEnd(&strm);
            return Z_ERRNO;
        }

        flush = [source hasBytesAvailable] ? Z_NO_FLUSH : Z_FINISH;
        strm.avail_in = (uInt)res;
        strm.next_in = inBuf;

        do {
            strm.avail_out = CHUNK;
            strm.next_out = outBuf;
            ret = deflate(&strm, flush);
            assert(ret != Z_STREAM_ERROR);
            have = CHUNK - strm.avail_out;

            res = [dest write:outBuf maxLength:have];
            if (res != have || res < 0) {
                (void)deflateEnd(&strm);
                return Z_ERRNO;
            }
        } while (strm.avail_out == 0);
        assert(strm.avail_in == 0);
    } while (flush != Z_FINISH);
    assert(ret == Z_STREAM_END);

    (void)deflateEnd(&strm);
    return Z_OK;
}
```

Afterwards the compressed data will be processed further (undergo encryption, etc) and saved.

And then for Android version which I am currently working on, from the document page [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/Deflater.html#DEFAULT_STRATEGY) the `Deflater` class perform deflation with `zlib` logic, so I tried with the following code segment:

```
byte[] dataToBeDeflated = inputString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

Deflater deflater = null;
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = null;
byte[] deflatedData = null;

try {
    deflater = new Deflater();
    deflater.setStrategy(Deflater.DEFAULT_STRATEGY);
    deflater.setLevel(Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);
    deflater.setInput(dataToBeDeflated);
    outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(dataToBeDeflated.length);
    deflater.finish();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (!deflater.finished()) {
        int count = deflater.deflate(buffer);
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }

    deflatedData = outputStream.toByteArray();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Deflate exception", e);
} finally {
    if (outputStream != null) {
        try {
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to close the output stream", e);
        }
    }
}
```

However, the result returned by the above implementation on Android doesn't yield the same result as in iOS, making it not usable by my existing iOS app.

Using the test string I quoted, iOS yield `NSData` of size 197 bytes, where the original string data is 273 bytes. While the original input on Android is also of size 273 bytes, but the above implementation gives a result of size 185.

Changing the logic on iOS side would not be viable currently as this would involve many additional process like submitting for review, etc.

I assume the underlying algorithm in both platforms should be the same? If this is the case why the results are different? Did I do something wrong and how can I correct it and obtain the same result on Android?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `16+MAX_WBITS` in `deflateInit2()` is requesting the gzip format, whereas the `Deflater` class is requesting the zlib format. You can get rid of the `16+` in the iOS code to request the zlib format.

Note that the output may still be different, since there is no requirement that the compressed data from different compressors be the same for the same input. All that matters is that you get the same thing from the decompressor that you gave to whichever compressor.

Answer (score 1):

There are two deflate methods in iOS:

```
1. deflateInit(strm, level)
2. deflateInit2(strm, level, method, windowBits, memLevel, strategy)
```

**1st one is compatible with the java's deflater**. Also make sure you are using same compression level in both iOS and Java(Android).

Compression Levels:

```
   -1: default
    0: NO_COMPRESSION
    1: BEST_SPEED //generally used 
       ......
    9: BEST_COMPRESSION
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you are using different levels, on iOS you are using `MAX_MEM_LEVEL` (9), while on Android you are using `DEFAULT_COMPRESSION`(-1). Try using `BEST_COMPRESSION`(9)  on Android.